# Javascript / jQuery countdown expires globally in each country in its midnight

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, global, countdown

this is time when countdown should expire, just example:

```
var bigDay = new Date("15 Jan 2019, 23:59:59");
```

Rest of the countdown code is already done.
Consider this time as midnight. Does this mean that the countdown will expire globally in each country in its local time at its midnight ?

For example in Europe will be midnight, countdown expires, but in Australia is just 9pm but countdown expires anyway because bigDay considers Europe time ?

What should I declare as bigDay to let countdown expire in midnight in each country on the world in its local midnight ?

I heard something about UNIX time, but not sure if and how it would solve this.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Unless your code explicitly uses the universal time APIs, JavaScript dates will use the local time zone of each client device. Also, you cannot rely on all browsers understanding a time format like the one you're using. Look into Moment.js or else use the native Date API to construct dates.

Comment: This code runs client side, so it will use the time on the client machine. So if someone has their time set to 1900, then it will count down for 118 years. If you want a reliable countdown, base it on a timestamp retrieved from a server in UTC